# Read file content which start with # using Spring Batch

Tags: java, spring, spring-batch, file-read

I have a very simple Spring Batch application which reads multiple file and write it to one file. My project is working super fine in all scenario except if a line start with "#" in my file. My reader doesn't read that line. Problem is that the upper system is going to send down the files where everyline start with # :(

Does anyone faced similar issue and how to solve it.

Thanks in advance..

My tokenizerconfig

```
<bean id="accountDataTokenizer" class="org.springframework.batch.item.file.transform.PatternMatchingCompositeLineTokenizer">
    <property name="tokenizers">
        <map>
            <entry key="#ACCOUNT*" value-ref="headerRecordTokenizer" />
            <entry key="*" value-ref="defaultLineTokenizer" />
        </map>
    </property>
</bean>
```

Comment: Could you post your current Spring Batch configuration? And what do you want to do with such lines? Ignore them?

Comment: The input file is being generated from some other system. That system generate that file in a way where each line start with "#". Now when i am reading those files i dont get any content in my reader, But if i remove the "#" from each line its all working fine.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `FlatFileItemReader` provides the ability to set a string that identifies commented out lines.  This is done via the `FlatFileItemReader#setComments(String[] prefixes)` configuration.  So in your case, you'd configure your `FlatFileItemReader` as follows:

```
@Bean
public FlatFileItemReader reader() {
    FlatFileItemReader reader = new FlatFileItemReader();
    ...
    reader.setComments(new String[] {"#"});
    return reader;
}
```

You can read more about the `FlatFileItemReader` and this method in the documentation here: https://docs.spring.io/spring-batch/trunk/apidocs/org/springframework/batch/item/file/FlatFileItemReader.html

Comment: Thanks Michael Minella. I got what you want to say and have implemented the same. I have used configuration to override the predefined comment value due to which reader was recognizing all my lines as comment.

Comment: I am able to get handle of data with # but not able to tokenize properly.   My inputfile is like :  #Account:12345,234,12                                                     when i use a tokenizer it doesn't tokenize the line with names and gives data in token array format.. I have updated my tokenizer config in question.

Comment: I figured out the reason of tokenizer issue. I am using a defaulttokenizer for which key is "*" and when we sort the key * comes at very top and hence all the lines were being tokenized by default tokenizer. I have removed the default tokenizer and its working now.

Answer (score 0):

If the first line is always "#" you can skip to read the first line of the file by adding this property into the itemReader (FlatFileItemReader):

Comment: Its not only first line, for each line first character is "#"

Comment: In a Spring-Batch Job normally there are 3 classes: a Reader, a Processor and a Writer. In the class that implements ItemProcessor you have a method called "process" that receive a java bean of the readed row as input. You can remove the character in this method or (another way) you can modify the java bean that rapresents the file structure, you can change the getXXX method (where XXX is the name of your field) and remove the special character before returning the value. I hope that these suggestions can be useful for you.

Comment: :Thanks for your suggestion . I understood what you are suggesting here but I am not getting contents in my reader itself (I have written custom reader) so there is no way i can map it to any POJO as i don't have handle of item. So at the very first iteration itself reader returns null which indicates that reading is done but my reader hasn't returned any content yet, So i dont have that handle in my processor.